# C++ cannot identify the overflow (Windows)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is a simple problem:

```
int main()
{

    long int a = 100000;
    long int b = 100000;
    long int c = a*b;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

The output for this (in MSVC) is `1410065408` where one would expect 1 followed by 10 of 0's. I use long ints which the container is large enough for a number of this size if I am not mistaken. Why does this occur?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-do-i-detect-unsigned-integer-multiply-overflow

Comment: The minimum size of a `long` is a 32 bit type. Windows uses that for example. And that's not large enough for 100000 * 100000.

Comment: Because signed integer overflow invokes undefined behaviour. Your program might crash, it might appear to work, it might print exactly `1410065408`, it might read you a bedtime story.

Comment: oh, I did not realize it was 32 bit on windows. Hmm.

Comment: Use -fsanitaze=undefined option when compiling. It will check for overflow and other undefined behaviour in runtime (so use it only for testing since it will slow program down)

Comment: @miszcz2137 is that option available for gcc?

Comment: @SilverFlash even on 64-bit Windows long is still a 32-bit type because Windows uses [LLP64 model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models)

Comment: @Waqar It certainly is for gcc, but not sure if windows also (MinGW isn't exactly gcc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out the limits of integer types on your platform you can use `numeric_limits`. Results are not the same on different platforms. In your case `long` is probably a 32 bit integer.

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\t'
              << std::numeric_limits<long>::max() << '\t'
              << std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: yep, seems to be the case. solved it with _int64 type for windows.

Comment: @SilverFlash: Don't use `_int64` as it's not portable. Use a `long long` or even a fixed width type like `std::int64_t`.